# How to write chords, notes and lyrics on MuseScore

Tags: sheet-music, musescore

Already spent some time trying to achieve it with no success.

As in the example, I want to have in the sheet music:

- Above the lines, the chords
- Below the lines

  - The notes
  - The lyrics

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write out the music first.
2. To add the chord symbols use `Add/Text/Chord Symbol`.
3. I don't think there is a set way to add the note names below the notes, but you can use sticking `Add/Text/Sticking`.
   To have these line up horizontally deselect automatic placement with the Properties panel (MuseScore 4) or the Inspector (MuseScore 3).
4. Add the lyrics with `Add/Text/Lyrics`.

Tip: When entering these you can use space (or hyphen) to move to the next note.

Answer (score 0):

For chords read the documentation on adding chord symbols:

https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/chord-symbols

For lyrics checkout

https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/lyrics

You can do the note names over the lyrics by entering the note names as lyrics and the actual lyrics as second stanza below.